# Magento 1.9 remove item from Checkout Page

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to remove an item from the cart, but I need to remove it on the payment page (checkout)

I'm using the following code

```
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$cartItemId = 651;
$cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($cartItemId)->save();
```

but the product is not removed, am I doing it wrong? I saw that there is a URL to delete the item from the checkout page
checkout/cart/delete/id/

but I don't know how to execute this, as soon as I load the page, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete it from the `Quote` instead of the `Cart` since you are past the Cart page already.

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
```

Or

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load(quote_id);
```

To see items:

```
$quote->getAllItems()
```

Remove item:

```
$quote->removeItem($itemId);
$quote->save();
```

Comment: only removed if i pass checkout link id/cart/delete/id/19801/, 
where can i find this ID?

Comment: ok, so get this id with, $quote->getitemId();